# How to edit .cs files created with Visual Studio with python 3 script

Tags: c#, python, unicode

I'm trying to write a python script to search and replace in some of my C# code, but I'm having trouble with encodings and BOM's.  For example, I'm trying to compare a string at the beginning of the file, but the BOM is causing a match to not match.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
if lines[0] == '//\n':
    # fails even though the file begins with //
```

Comment: dunno about python but c# doesn't include the end of line char in the lines ready by way of readline.  What's a BOM

Comment: BOM is Byte Order Mark.  It's used to signal how the file has been encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to the open call.  Both the reading and writing calls have to have it.